# Phonegap iOS retrieve device language

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm doing a Phonegap hybrid app and i have to retrieve the device language, eg: "IT", "EN". Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Regarding your question the answers is:

```
 var lang = navigator.language.split("-");
 var current_lang = (lang[0]);
 alert( "current_lang: " + current_lang );
```

Comment: Small problem with the code above, it should be `alert(current_lang);` without the quotes.

Comment: Note that this won't work for old Android (2.x). See: https://github.com/lavinjj/angularjs-localizationservice/issues/6

Answer (score 4):

There's (now) the Globalization API in Cordova to retrieve that kind of info (you can also get info for dates, currency, ...):

```
globalization.getPreferredLanguage
globalization.getLocaleName
globalization.dateToString
globalization.stringToDate
globalization.getDatePattern
globalization.getDateNames
globalization.isDayLightSavingsTime
globalization.getFirstDayOfWeek
globalization.numberToString
globalization.stringToNumber
globalization.getNumberPattern
globalization.getCurrencyPattern
```

See http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_globalization_globalization.md.html#Globalization