# build phonegap application multiple languages interfaces

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins, multilingual

I want to create phonegap application that has two interfaces one in English language the lets say other one French ..

What is the best practice to do that? is there any way or pre-defined method?

should I use local storage?

can any one give me tips or clear code example?

my application uses html , jquery mobile, json , external mysql database, and php

Comment: This can help you a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11625807/1320764, checking device language and switching app's default to recieved is a good practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to approach this, but the ones I've seen used the most is defaulting to English and then letting the user set the language in some sort of options menu.  This option would probably be stored locally but it can be stored for the account if the app is going to be installed on multiple devices and you want syncing between devices.  I don't have any code at the moment but its just a variable check on what interface to display which should be pretty simple to implement.

Comment: I used this method but how could I keep the chosen user language preference when accessing the app next time?

If I set the default language to English it will return to English on each page load? right??

Answer (score 0):

I would create a table named "Dictionary" with the columns: Lang, key, Translation

Lang+key are your primar key

So let say English=0,France=1

You have records like:

0, yes, yes

1, yes, wee

And so on..

In your code you specify the sentence's key instead of the whole text when you use text